# Why does my variable live outside its scope

Tags: c++, scope

My understanding is that variables that are created inside a while or for loop disposed/deleted from memory after the loop is done executing (see [reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556449/are-variables-inside-a-loop-while-or-for-disposed-after-the-loop-has-completed)). 
But why does the following code show the variable is using the value from PREVIOUS loop? Is that is because stringstream variable have some special power?

The following is my C++ code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str="1A2";
    stringstream ss(str);
    int intVar;
    while(ss.good()){
        char charVar;
        ss >> intVar;
        ss>> charVar;
        cout<<"intVar="<<intVar << " charVar="<<charVar<<endl;
    }   
}
```

The following 2 lines are actual output:

```
intVar=1 charVar=A
intVar=2 charVar=A
```

Why it is not the following 2 lines?

```
intVar=1 charVar=A
intVar=2 charVar=
```

Comment: Check what the `operator>>` function *returns*. If you do `if (ss >> charVar) { ... } else { ... }` then the `else` branch would be taken.

Comment: Also please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) Doing `while (ss.good())` is just as bad.

Comment: Always initialise your variables.

Comment: @Some programmer dude : Your suggestion does fix the strange behavior. I will study your suggestions and update for meaningful results. Many thanks.

Comment: @molbdnilo : Thanks for this suggestion. But simply provide an initial value do not help. Plus, it is not always possible to give meaningful initial value.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a meaningful value, just something you can *expect*. Otherwise the behavior can be undefined, and you'll just end up scratching your head wondering "WTF!?!".

Answer (score 7):

First of all there's a difference between *scope* and *life-time*.

The *life-time* of the variable `charVar` ends each iteration, but the variable is still in *scope* inside the loop.

Also you need to know that the value of uninitialized "local" variables is *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Reading uninitialized variables (which happen as part of the output) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is what you're experiencing here.

What happens practically is that the memory used for the variable `charVar` doesn't change, the compiler *reuses* the same location each iteration. And since you don't modify that memory it will simply retain the last value stored in that memory.

Comment: Thanks. Here is my two confirmation : 1) After research, I plan to use: `while(!ss.fail())` to replace `while(ss.good())`;    2) When I print out the address of charVar, I can see the memory address does not change:        `cout<<"intVar="<<intVar << " charVar="<<charVar<<"! &charVar=" << static_cast<const void *> (&charVar)<<  endl;`

Answer (score 0):

This  because the loop has not  ended before the value was printed and as their was no value to enter during the last iteration in charvar it would retain its value from the second last time.
The scope of the variable is only in the loop put it doesn't get destroyed until the very last iteration of the loop. 
Hope I made sense